# Problem that may use Borel Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers, borel-cantelli-lemmas

So, there is a sequence of identically distributed independent random variables taking values on the integers, and they have a positive expectation. The problem is to prove that with probability 1 the sum from 1 to k of the random variables is 0 for finitely many k.

I was thinking to use the first Borel Cantelli Lemma, but I can't seem to show that the sum of the probabilities is finite.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually this is the opposite, you need to check that $\sum P(X_n\ne0)$ *diverges*.

Comment: You might have better luck with the Law of Large Numbers: If $S_k$ is the sum of the first $k$ of your random variables, and $\mu$ is their common mean, then $S_k/k\to\mu>0$ a.s.

Comment: @Did that would be if I wanted to use the second Borel Cantelli Lemma, but that would require the events to be independent, which they are not

Comment: Are they not? Quote: "a sequence of identically distributed `independent` random variables"

Comment: @Did i think the proof should go in the way that assume $A_k=\{x:\sum_{i=1}^k X_i(x)=0\}$ and show that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(A_i)<\infty$ then Borel Cantelli first lemma $\mathbb P(A_i i.o.)=0$ and hence $\mathbb P(A_k)=0$ for finitely many $k$ with probability $1$.

Comment: @bunny Sorry but the assertions that [$P(A_k\ \text{i.o.})=0$] and that [$P(A_k)=0$ for finitely many $k$] are simply not related. Additionally, the assertion that [$P(A_k)=0$ for finitely many $k$ with probability $1$] is absurd.

Comment: @Did sorry i mean to say that when i have $\mathbb P(A_i i.o.)=0$ then $\mathbb P(\sum_{i=1}^kX_i=0) $ for finitely many $k $ with probability $1$.

Comment: @bunny Again, the statement [$P(X_1+\cdots+X_k=0)$ for finitely many $k$] is absurd.

Comment: how is it absurd? Even if you read he question both the things are sane

Comment: @bunny Sorry but 1. you seem to be mathematically lost, 2. you are hijacking a comment thread, 3. you are not using the notification @, 4. you are seemingly not reading my comments. Thus, if you have a new question, do not be shy and just post it.